# LaTeX package for drawing MBQC patterns

Tags: programming

I'm looking for an appropriate $\LaTeX$ package for drawing measurement-based quantum computing patterns similar to the picture below:

[image]

Does anyone know of a package which may be most efficient for drawing diagrams like this? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belong to SE on LaTeX.

Comment: @MartinVesely Fair enough. I also considered posting there, but a quick search showed many TeX-related posts on QC.SE. Plus I was curious to find out whether any MBQC-specific tailored packages exist, which seemed better-suited to ask here.

Comment: Look at: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/152/278

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this be more appropriate in the [LaTeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)? Nevertheless, here's my suggestion using `tkz-graph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetVertexNormal[TextColor=red]
    \SetGraphUnit{2}
    \Vertex[L=$\ket{\psi}_1$]{s}
    \node at (s)[above=3ex]{\textcolor{red}{$M(\theta), s_1$}};
    \EA[L=$\ket{+}_2$](s){c}
    \Edge(s)(c)
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{fig:reference}The \textcolor{red}{$J(-\theta)$}-gate MBQC pattern.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Using `\tikzset` to set some parameters only once is certainly possible, but first you can see if the syntax suits your needs.